# Excel how summarize values in

Tags: excel, charts

I have a column of data like the one below under "DATA".  How can I create a chart which which would summarize each unique value like:

```
CPU Utilization Alert 6
Free Memory Alert 1
System Uptime Alert 2
```

DATA:

```
CPU Utilization Alert 
CPU Utilization Alert 
Free Memory Alert 
System Uptime Alert 
CPU Utilization Alert 
CPU Utilization Alert 
CPU Utilization Alert 
System Uptime Alert 
CPU Utilization Alert
```

-Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use a pivot table, Putting the data column in both the Rows and the Values:

[image]

Comment: When I try this I get the column of "Data" items in column A, but I see no way to add the "Count of Data" under "Values".

Comment: Just drag the Data column from the fields list into the values, it will automatically change to `Count of Data`

Comment: @zBernie if this worked please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: I don't see a check mark anywhere on the page.  I'm new here!  :)

Comment: @zBernie upper right hand corner of the answer just below the down arrow below the `1`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not seeing the check mark.  I even tried a different browser.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Scott that using Pivot Table is the fastest approach especially when you only after a quick summary of the counts per data type.

If you literately want a *chart*, you can highlight your data and insert a `Pivot Chart`, which will ask you to set up a pivot table (as demonstrated by Scott), and then let you display the result in a chart. The chart I used is a **Pie Chart** as demonstrated below:

[image: Demo]

Comment: Thanks, that's a useful option.